# IDictionary<TKey, TValue> in .NET 4 not covariant

Tags: .net, dictionary, .net-4.0, covariance

The `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET 4 / Silverlight 4 does not support covariance, i.e. I can't do a

```
IDictionary<string, object> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

analog to what I can do with `IEnumerable<T>`s now.

Probably boils down to the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` not being covariant either. I feel that covariance should be allowed in dictionaries at least for the values.

So is that a bug or a feature? Will it ever come, maybe in .NET 37.4?

UPDATE (2 years later):

There will be an [`IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548(v=VS.110).aspx) in .NET 4.5, but it won't be covariant either `:·/`, because it derives from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is not an interface and thus cannot be covariant.

The BCL team would have to redesign a lot to come up and use some `ICovariantPair<TKey, TValue>` instead. Also strongly-typed indexers á la `this[TKey key]` aren't possible for covariant interfaces. A similar end can only be achieved by placing an extension method `GetValue<>(this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> self, TKey key)` somewhere which would somehow internally have to call an an actual implementation, which arguably looks like a quite messy approach.

Comment: Thanks for providing the update on .NET 4.5. IMHO it would be useful to have covariance on a read-only dictionary so it's too bad that it's not looking like it will be supported.

Comment: A `IReadOnlyDictionary` wrapper that supports upcasting can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56595603/11178549). It can wrap a dictionary of strings and expose it as a dictionary of objects.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's a feature. .NET 4.0 only supports **safe** covariance. The cast you mentioned is potentially dangerous as you could add a non-string element to the dictionary if that was possible:

```
IDictionary<string, object> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict["hello"] = 5; // not an string
```

On the other hand, `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface. The `T` type parameter is only in its output positions (return type of the `Current` property) so it's safe to treat `IEnumerable<string>` as an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: Ahh ok, of course, I indeed was intending for read-only use. The .NET library surely does miss a read-only Dictionary type. Someone should post another question about that issue one of these days. ;-)

Comment: In theory covariance is safe, but a quirk from .Net 1.0 may throw a slight spanner in the works.  Because `Derived[]` is considered to inherit from `Base[]`, a `Derived[]` will implement `IList<Base>`; such an `IList<Base>` will work correctly for reading, but will throw an exception when written to.

Comment: Stupid because `ReadOnlyDictionary` and `ImmutableDictionary` should not have this issue

Answer (score 14):

But then you could say

```
myDict.Add("Hello, world!", new DateTime(2010, 1, 27));
```

which would fail miserably. The issue is that the `TValue` in `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is used in both input and output positions. To wit:

```
myDict.Add(key, value);
```

and

```
TValue value = myDict[key];
```

> So is that a bug or a feature?

It's by design.

> Will it ever come, maybe in .NET 37.4?

No, it's inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, but with more specialised derived types (rather than object which everything derives from)

The trick is to make the method generic and put a where clause putting the relevant restriction.
Assuming that you're dealing with base types and derived types, the following works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericsTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        p.Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {

        Dictionary<long, SpecialType1> a = new Dictionary<long, SpecialType1> {
        { 1, new SpecialType1 { BaseData = "hello", Special1 = 1 } },
        { 2, new SpecialType1 { BaseData = "goodbye", Special1 = 2 } } };

        Test(a);
    }

    void Test<Y>(Dictionary<long, Y> data) where Y : BaseType
    {
        foreach (BaseType x in data.Values)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(x.BaseData);
        }
    }
}

public class BaseType
{
    public string BaseData { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialType1 : BaseType
{
    public int Special1 { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: this is a great workaround!  It allows me to do exactly what I need to do for code re-use, and completely avoids the problem that covariance would introduce.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4 only supports *out* covariance not *in*. It works with IEnumerable because IEnumerable is read only.

Comment: "in covariance" is a misnomer. That would be contravariance, and it is supported in .NET 4 and is useful in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need a specific operations from a Dictionary, you could create a wrapper:

```
class Container
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public object GetByKey(string key) => myDict[key];
}
```

or even implement the interface that you need in Container.

Answer (score -1):

A work around for a specific type of useful covariance on [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IDictionary.aspx)

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> ToReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> toWrap)
    {
        var intermediate = toWrap.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value!=null ? 
                                        a.Value.ToArray().AsEnumerable() : null);
        var wrapper = new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>(intermediate);
        return wrapper;
    }   
}
```