# IReadOnlyDictionary lack of covariance

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, covariance

I've read the related question ([How to get around lack of covariance with IReadOnlyDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593900/how-to-get-around-lack-of-covariance-with-ireadonlydictionary)), but I don't understand how it can help with my issue.

Here is the `Box` which can be edited (using `IBoxTarget`) and notify about changes (using `IBoxSource`):

```
interface IBoxTarget
{
    void DoSomething();
}

interface IBoxSource
{
    event Action SomethingIsDone;
}

class Box : IBoxTarget, IBoxSource
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // . . . some logic . . .

        if (SomethingIsDone != null) SomethingIsDone();
    }

    public event Action SomethingIsDone;
}
```

`Room` is a container of `Box`. It also implements two interfaces:

```
interface IRoomTarget
{
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IBoxTarget> Boxes { get; }
}

interface IRoomSource
{
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IBoxSource> Boxes { get; }
}

class Room : IRoomTarget, IRoomSource
{
    Dictionary<string, Box> boxes = new Dictionary<string, Box>();

    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IBoxTarget> IRoomTarget.Boxes
    {
        get { return boxes; } // Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type ..."
    }

    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IBoxSource> IRoomSource.Boxes
    {
        get { return boxes; } // Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type ..."
    }
}
```

I don't want to create two different dictionaries inside `Room`. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case this helped:

```
interface IRoomTarget
{
    IBoxTarget this[string name] { get; }
}

interface IRoomSource
{
    IBoxSource this[string name] { get; }
}

class Room : IRoomTarget, IRoomSource
{
    Dictionary<string, Box> boxes = new Dictionary<string, Box>();

    public IBoxTarget IRoomTarget.this[string name]
    {
        get { return boxes[name]; }
    }

    IBoxSource IRoomSource.this[string name]
    {
        get { return boxes[name]; }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that's universal solution