# Contravariance in a Dictionary value

Tags: c#, .net, contravariance

Why is this not legitimate code?

```
 public interface IExcelExport<in T>
{
    byte[] ExportSheetsToExcel(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>> data, bool formatDateColumns = true);
}
```

Which gives this error.

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IExcelExport<T>.ExportSheetsToExcel(IDictionary<string, List<T>>, bool)'. 'T' is contravariant.
```

Why can't i use a contravariant type as a dictionary value?  Any potential workarounds?

Comment: Because dictionary is not covariant

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13602918/3177092) is interesting?