# Confusion about covariance

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I am developing a generic class and related generic methods.  I believe the problem I am about to describe has to do with Covariance, but I can't figure out what the compiler wants me to do.

**Edit: adding code which shows how I populate the dict**

There is abstract base class NetworkNode.  Concrete class PowerNetworkNode inherits from it.  Now I have a function which will not compile.  What changes should I make to get this to compile and have the desired functionality?

In abc NetworkNode, we have

```
public abstract IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
        hydrateNodes<NetworkNode>(string nodesTableName);
```

In the concrete class, PowerNetworkNode, this is overridden by

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
        hydrateNodes<NetworkNode>(string nodesTableName)
    {
        IDictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode> returnDict = 
             new Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>();

        // code elided
        returnDict[Convert.ToUInt32(oid)] =
             new PowerNetworkNode(oid, minPow, maxPow, edges, fuelType, ngID);
        // NetworkNode doesn't have all the fields that PowerNetworkNode has.

        return returnDict;
    }
```

The compiler error message is:

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<uint,  
CImodeller.Model.NetworkElements.PowerNetworkNode>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

When I change the code to this:

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
        hydrateNodes<NetworkNode>(string nodesTableName)
    {
        IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> returnDict = 
             new Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>();

        // code elided

        return returnDict;
    }
```

in which the line with "new Dictionary" now creates one with NetworkNode and not PowerNetworkNode, the compiler states

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<uint,
CImodeller.Model.NetworkElements.PowerNetworkNode>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I understand what this means, but I don't know what I should change to get it to work.

Comment: `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not variant nor by `TKey`, nor by `TValue`.

Comment: PetSerAI Well that answers a lot.  (I'm not being sarcastic.)  Is there anything define as <out TValue> that I can use covariantly which is also a key value pair?

Comment: Ant P, that raises a different kind of error.  I have updated my question to cover what happens.

Comment: Ant P, this still just moves the error to where it says,    returnDict[Convert.ToUInt32(oid)] =
                            new PowerNetworkNode(oid, minPow, maxPow, edges, fuelType, ngID);  Now it  says  Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'CImodeller.Model.NetworkElements.PowerNetworkNode' to 'NetworkNode'

Comment: Is `NetworkNode` supposed to be a class? At the moment it's a generic parameter of `hydrateNodes`. How are you supposed to populate the dictionary?

Comment: @philologon that code isn't in your question.

Comment: Lee, NetworkNode is an abstract class.  PowerNetworkNode is a concrete implementation of the class.  I populate the dictionary by reading a line from a csv file, creating a new instance of PowerNetworkNode, then add it to the dictionary.  I think PetSerAI is on the right track.  I thought IDictionary was covariant, but it isn't.

Comment: Ant P I was trying to keep unnecessary clutter out of the question for simplicity.  I will add a little bit because it seems now to be necessary.

Comment: `NetworkNode` isn't a class within `hydrateNodes`, it's a generic parameter. The client can choose any type for `NetworkNode` e.g. `IDictionary<uint, string> d = obj.hydrateNodes<string>()`. It looks like you need to move the generic parameter to the class instead of the `hydrateNodes` method.

Comment: Ant P, you don't have to assume it PowerNetworkNode derives from NetworkNode since I clearly state that in the OP.  Is there any other key/value pair I can use that is covariant in value?

Comment: It does seem as though you have some basic misconceptions about how generics work - as Lee notes, "NetworkNode" is just the name of the generic parameter in the context of the method; that doesn't imply that the *class* `NetworkNode` is in use here - try replacing `NetworkNode` with `T` and maybe it will make the issue a little clearer.

Comment: Yes, your first clue was the title of this question.  I will see if I can do this and report back.

Comment: Ant P, that doesn't work.  It goes back to the first error I reported.  As I say in my Answer, I am switching to an interface which is documented as being covariant, IEnumerable<out T>

Comment: Your problem is not (just) covariance, it is that `NetworkNode` does _not_ refer to the `NetworkNode` class you have defined but to any class the client chooses. You need to remove the generic parameter from `hydrateNodes` before you can begin to fix your issue.

Comment: Ant P, that does work in the sense that it makes the issue clearer.  As I say in my Answer, I am switching to an interface which is documented as being covariant, IEnumerable<out T>  But my real problem is that I need a covariant key-value pair.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593900/how-to-get-around-lack-of-covariance-with-ireadonlydictionary

Comment: Lee, thank you.  I see what you are saying.  I recently learned that co and contravariant in and out modifiers can only be added to interfaces or generic delegates.  I think part of my solution lies there somewhere, although I don't know exactly how yet.

Comment: Followup. I am deleting my Answer because I see it still doesn't apply to my real problem, which is I need a key value pair type of collection, but I don't see any in C# which are covariant in the Value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two misconceptions here - even before you reach your question - which is conflating the problem.

#### Generic type parameter names

The first issue has nothing to do with variance. Understand that this:

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
    hydrateNodes<NetworkNode>(string nodesTableName)
{
    IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> returnDict = 
         new Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>();
}
```

Is *exactly* equivalent to this:

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
    hydrateNodes<T>(string nodesTableName)
{
    IDictionary<uint, T> returnDict = 
         new Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>();
}
```

That is, the generic type parameter in the method name *does not refer* to an actual type, it just refers to what you are going to call that type *in the method*. If you call a method `public void DoSomething<SomeClass>`, this has nothing to do with a class called `SomeClass`.

It should be clear from the above that you can't assign a `Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>` to a `IDictionary<uint, T>` - you have no idea whether a `PowerNetworkNode` is a `T`.

However, if you look a little more closely, you'll realise that this method doesn't need to be generic at all - you always want `T` to be a NetworkNode, so just...

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
    hydrateNodes(string nodesTableName)
{
    IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> returnDict = 
         new Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>();
}
```

This is a step in the right direction but it leads to your next problem.

#### Variance

As you know, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is invariant in `TValue`, so you can't assign a `Dictionary<uint, PowerNetworkNode>` to a `IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode>`.

Now, you've mentioned in the comments that you want "a key/value pair type that is covariant in its value."

Bad news - you can't have one of those. It's inherently a contradiction. If you declare something as `Something<NetworkNode>` where you can *add* a NetworkNode, the compiler expects you to be able to add *any NetworkNode* to it. If you assign a `Something<PowerNetworkNode>` to that - you've broken that contract. That's why invariance exists: because it is a logical necessity.

The *good* news is that you shouldn't need to - you can put a `PowerNetworkNode` in an `IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode>` - because a `PowerNetworkNode` is a `NetworkNode`.

So (unless you're doing something very strange in the rest of the method), the following should be fine:

```
public override IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> 
    hydrateNodes(string nodesTableName)
{
    IDictionary<uint, NetworkNode> returnDict = 
         new Dictionary<uint, NetworkNode>();
}
```

Hopefully this has provided some insight.

Comment: Thank you for this. After thinking it over and reading your Answer, I now see that I need to rework my architecture at a fundamental level.