# Cannot implicitly convert type from non-covariant generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting, covariance

**Important edit**: Do not use a Dictionary in this context. It uses Object.GetHashCode() which isn't good for use as a dictionary key. I still learned something from this though.

I have the following declaration

```
private static IDictionary<IDictionary<string,string>, IEnumerable<Fishtank>> _cache;
```

and the following code to attempt to initialize it

```
if (_cache == null) 
  _cache = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string,string>, LinkedList<Fishtank>>();
```

The problem I'm having is the initialization generates a compile time error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary,System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I know that Dictionary and LinkedList implement IDictionary and IEnumerable respectively, so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: This is because IDictionary does not support covariance.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant

Comment: I see, I had thought I would always be able to cast to an implemented interface - thanks for the link

Comment: I added an edit because I discovered that using a Dictionary in the context I was (as a Dictionary key) doesn't work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do as below

```
if (_cache == null) 
    _cache = new Dictionary<IDictionary<string, string>, IEnumerable<Fishtank>>();
```