# Passing Dictionary as a parameter to a function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary

I created my data dictionary:

```
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
data.Add("customer", "TEST")
data.Add("secretKeyId", "2222222222222")
data.Add("secretKey", "333333333333333")
```

and I have the following function:

```
 Public Shared Function Create(ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As [String]
    ' Serializes the body into JSON using the fastJSON library.
    Dim json As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
    Dim body As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json) ....
```

How can I call the `Create` function and pass the `DATA` with all the keys and values that I entered to this function?

I tried: `create(data.all)` or `create(data)` but it is not working.

Comment: Please learn how to format your questions - which can be found using the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: can you expand on "its not working"; mindreading skills are at the cleaners, but why is it `Dictionary(Of String, String)` one place and `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` in the other?

Comment: I think, this is not supported based on an old answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant. Has anything changed on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an incompatible data type to your method: in your caller method your dictionary is of type `string, string` and your function awaits dictionary of type `string, object`. You have two solutions:

- either change the signature of your dictionary in the main part to `Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)`
- or change the signature to the dictionary parameter of the method to `ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, String)`

A possible solution looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function Create(ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As [String]
    ' Serializes the body into JSON using the fastJSON library.
    Dim json As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
    return json
end function
```

The call:

```
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
data.Add("customer", "TEST")
data.Add("secretKeyId", "2222222222222")
data.Add("secretKey", "333333333333333")
Dim dataAsJson = Create(data)
Console.WriteLine(dataAsJson)
```

The output:

```
{"customer":"TEST","secretKeyId":"2222222222222","secretKey":"333333333333333"}
```

This would also work correctly in this case and create the same result as above:

```
Public Shared Function Create(ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As [String]
    ' Serializes the body into JSON using the fastJSON library.
    Dim json As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
    return json
end function

Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
data.Add("customer", "TEST")
data.Add("secretKeyId", "2222222222222")
data.Add("secretKey", "333333333333333")
Dim dataAsJson = Create(data)
Console.WriteLine(dataAsJson)
```

Comment: Thanks pasty .  thanks for noticing it. I wasnt even looking at that

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.