# Generic interfaces with abstract implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, design-patterns, graph

I am trying to implement some graph searching algorithms in .NET for fun and personal education. For my implementation, I chose to start with a Node class that implemented the following interface:

```
public interface INode<T>
{
    T Data { get; }

    IDictionary<INode<T>, int> Neighbors { get; set; }
}
```

The node contains some `Data` of type T, as well as a dictionary of nodes that it shares an edge with along with their integer distance. I then thought that I could create an abstract `Node` class:

```
public abstract class Node<T> : INode<T>
{
    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public IDictionary<INode<T>, int> Neighbors { get; private set; }

    public Node(T data, IDictionary<Node<T>, int> neighbors)
    {
        this.Data = data;

        this.Neighbors = neighbors;
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work, however, since `neighbors` doesn't match `Neighbors`. I would like whatever parameters are in `Node`'s constructor to include an `IDictionary` of that specific type of `Node` and not just something that implements `INode`. For example, I might later create a concrete class called GraphNode, and I want to be sure that only GraphNodes are used in the constructor.

To solve this, I could simply take the IDictionary Neighbors out of INode and put it into the abstract Node class. This could limit my ability to test the class later on though using a framework like FakeItEasy, and I'm not sure what other implications it might have down the line.

I would appreciate some suggestions on how to generally approach this problem. If there is no best solution, then what are some pros and cons of various solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the given code, there are two things that you can do to make this compile.

First, the code also doesn't compile because `INode<T>` is not fully implemented. Your interface defines a `set` method for `Neighbors`, so your `set` will have to be public, or you will have to explicitly implement that property.

Second, presuming you really want to restrict your constructor to take `neighbors` as a dictionary keyed on the `Node<T>` class, and not the interface, the quickest thing you can do to load up `this.Neighbors` is change the line to

```
this.Neighbors = neighbors.ToDictionary(
    neighborDistance => (INode<T>)neighborDistance.Key,
    neighborDistance => neighborDistance.Value
);
```

Something like this must be done because generic `IDictionary` [is not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant?rq=1).