# Using JSON.NET converter to deserialize Dictionary with interface value

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Given these class definitions:

```
public class TypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
}

public interface ISubStuff
{
    string Item { get; set; }
}

public class SubStuff : ISubStuff
{
   public string Item { get; set; }
}

public interface IMainStuff
{
    Dictionary<string, ISubStuff> SubStuff { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use the TypeConverter class in method declaration for deserialization as below but it's NOT working:

```
public class MainStuff : IMainStuff
{ 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeConverter<Dictionary<string, SubStuff>>))] 
    public Dictionary<string, ISubStuff> SubStuff
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } 
}
```

The call below to deserialize the json causes an `unable to cast object of type Dictionary<string, SubStuff> to Dictionary<string, ISubStuff>` exception.

```
var jsonText = "{ \"SubStuff\": { } }"; 
var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainStuff><jsonText);
```

Comment: can you please be more specific? what does not work? is it not compiling? is it compiling but throwing run time error? is it compiling but the attribute is not working?

Comment: You want to do X, you think Y (above question) is the way to do it. But Y doesn't work. We don't have enough info to guess what you want to to do with Y , and no idea what X is...

Comment: The error is unable to cast object of type Dictionary<string, SubStuff> to Dictionary<string, ISubStuff>.

Comment: @SusanLee Just look at the code what you've posted so far plus the error message... And now assume you see this question at SO and want to answer it. All you know is above.. What additional info would you need?

Comment: Instead of what I have how do you make the declaration such that it will not cause this error and will correctly deserialize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the c# `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).  I.e., even though `SubStuff` *is an* `ISubStuff`, [`Dictionary<string, SubStuff>` *is **not** a* `Dictionary<string, ISubStuff>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant).  Thus when Json.NET tries to set the `Dictionary<string, SubStuff>` back into the `MainStuff.SubStuff` property, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

For a general explanation of why read/write collections are not covariant, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase).  Its discussion of the lack of covariance of `List<T>` applies equally to generic dictionaries.

What you can do is use [`JsonProperty.ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) to apply your `TypeConverter<T>` only to the *values* in the dictionary, like so:

```
public class MainStuff : IMainStuff
{ 
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TypeConverter<SubStuff>))]
    public Dictionary<string, ISubStuff> SubStuff
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } 
}

public class TypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) 
    {
        var msg = string.Format("This converter should be applied directly with [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TypeConverter<{0}>))] or [JsonProperty(typeof(TypeConverter<{0}>))]", 
                                typeof(T));
        throw new NotImplementedException(msg);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0LwOCX).

Incidentally, rather than inheriting from `JsonConverter`, you could inherit from [`CustomCreationConverter<>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm) instead:

```
public class MainStuff : IMainStuff
{ 
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TypeConverter<ISubStuff, SubStuff>))]
    public Dictionary<string, ISubStuff> SubStuff
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } 
}

public class TypeConverter<T, TSerialized> : CustomCreationConverter<T> 
    where TSerialized : T, new()
{
    public override T Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new TSerialized();
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XwXOn4).

Finally, as an alternative, you could investigate use of the [`TypeNameHandling` setting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I have a more complex scenario here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/JSoAug
Can you please take a look?

Comment: @SusanLee - that's complicated enough that you might want to ask another question, as the preferred format on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  Did you try `TypeConverter<T>` as well as `TypeConverter<T, TSerialized>`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Created new question for this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663658/deserializing-complex-nested-dictionary-type-using-json-net