# Issues with C# Covariance in .NET when create a nested, JSON serializable object structure using Dictionaries & Generics

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, generics, covariance

I am experiencing some issues in creating a nested object structure in C# using Dictionaries & Generics (I am using Visual Studio, .NET Framework 4.6+)

The main problem is the absence of covariance in C# Dictionaries.

I have to create this simple (JSON serializable/deserializable) object structure in C#. I try to explain using the animals...

```
public class AnimalCatalog
{
    public Dictionary<string, Animal> AnimalsDict { get; set; }   // key is the species name
}

public class Animal   // base class
{
    public string Species { get; set; }   // univocal
    public bool CanFly  { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, GenericPaw> PawsDict { get; set; }   // each animal has a different type and a different number of paws
}

public class GenericPaw   // base class
{
    public int FingerNumber { get; set; }   // number of finger in each paw
}

public class Cat : Animal   // derived class
{
    public void meow()   // only cats says 'meow'
    {...}
}

public class CatPaw : GenericPaw   // derived class
{
    public void scratch()   // cats paws could scratch something :) but not all the animals paws could
    {...}
}
```

I implemented this structure using C# generics, because a Cat has a dictionary of CatPaws, not generic Paws :P. this is my proposal.

```
public class AnimalCatalog<T,V> where T : Animal<V> where V : GenericPaw 
{
    public Dictionary<string, T> AnimalsDict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, T>();  // key is the species name
}

public class Animal<T> where T : GenericPaw   // base class
{
    public string Species { get; set; }   // univocal
    public bool CanFly  { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, T> PawsDict { get; set; }   // each animal has a different type and a different number of paws
}

public class GenericPaw   // base class
{
    public string PawName { get; set; }   // univocal
    public int FingerNumber { get; set; }   // number of finger in each paw
}

public class Cat<T> : Animal<T> where T : CatPaw   // derived class
{
    public void meow()   // only cats says 'meow'
    {...}
}

public class CatPaw : GenericPaw   // derived class
{
    public void scratch()   // cats paws could scratch something :) but not all the animals paws could
    {...}
}
```

let's use the created class

```
Cat<CatPaw> Kitty = new Cat<CatPaw>();   // create a cat
CatPaw KittyFirstPaw = new CatPaw();   // create the 1st cat's paw
Kitty.PawsDict.Add(KittyFirstPaw.PawName, KittyFirstPaw);   // add the paw to the dict
AnimalCatalog<Animal<GenericPaw>,GenericPaw> ZooCatalog = new AnimalCatalog<Animal<GenericPaw>,GenericPaw>();   // create a catalog of animals
Animal<GenericPaw> GenericAnimal = Kitty;   <-- doens't compile (can't convert derived to base class)
AnimalCatalog.AnimalsDict.Add(GenericAnimal.Species, GenericAnimal);
```

I also tried using an interface instead of a base class, using the out keyword to specify T as a covariant type, but it doesn't work because I can't use a covariant type in a dict...

Any help is very appreciated :)
Stefano

Comment: Shouldn't your base class `GenericPaw` be declared as abstract

Comment: Not all animals have paws or lookalikes (snakes for example) :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert `Cat<CatPaw>` to `Animal<GenericPow>`, because then you could add a different kind of `GenericPaw` into its dictionary (for example a `DogPaw`)  and the cat wouldn't appreciate that.

This is only a problem because you can insert new values in the dictionary, so it seems like it could be solved by using an `IReadOnlyDictionary`, but unfortunately that one isn't covariant either because of technical issues as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant).

On a side note, is there a reason why `Cat` is also generic?

```
public class Cat<T> : Animal<T> where T : CatPaw
```

That would be useful if you want to create a cat that can only have certain specific paws derived from `CatPaw`. If not, this could become:

```
public class Cat : Animal<CatPaw>
```

The `AnimalCatalog` also seems like it's unnecessarily complex. If you only ever need an animal catalog of `Animal`, it could be simplified to just one generic parameter:

```
public class AnimalCatalog<TPaw> where TPaw : GenericPaw
{
    public Dictionary<string, Animal<TPaw>> AnimalsDict { get; set; }
}
```

and if you only ever need an `AnimalCatalog<GenericPaw>`, you could get rid of the one parameter too. But it's still the case that this catalog would not be very useful since you can't convert an `Animal<CatPaw>` to `Animal<GenericPaw>`.

To solve this, you could create a convariant interface of `IAnimal<out TPaw>` that has all the properties of an `Animal` but instead of the dictionary, you could either expose paws as an `IEnumerable<TPaw> Paws` and if you need the dictionary lookup, a method: `TPaw GetPaw(string pawName)`. These would be implemented using the dictionary. Then it's possible to convert a `Cat` ( which is an `Animal<CatPaw>` and therefore also `IAnimal<CatPaw>`) to `IAnimal<GenericPaw>`. Your animal catalog will then contain `IAnimal<GenericPaw>`.

Comment: A cat with a hoof, paw, claw and hand, won't be a happy cat!

Comment: The trick without using generics is this: Cat Kitty= new Cat(); Animal GenericAnimal=Kitty; but using generics this is not possible...

Comment: @ Neme thank u very much, I'm trying to convert the Zoo into the correct objects, I'll let u know... :)

Answer (score 0):

Only Interfaces and Delegates allow Covariance. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: GenericPaw already looks like an interface, so it seems OP was on the right track, just not there yet.

Comment: Yes, right, I tried to use interfaces instead of base classes. Using generics types with the 'out' keyword (to specify covariant type) is not allowed if type is used in a dictionary :(

Comment: @Mixxiphoid its Animal that shoud be an Interface.

Comment: @keuleJ true, I think both should be interfaces. The name of GenericPaw was already hinting that is should be interface.

Comment: @Stefano Why isn't is just an IEnumerable<IPaw>? The type could be a property of the Ipaw.

Comment: @ Mixxiphoid IEnumerable is read only and don't allow me to use dictionary, that is very important for the animals in the catalog :)